# Hibernate5Module doesn't fetch OneToMany collection

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, lombok

First of all I have had two related entities mapped with bidirectional OneToMany:

```
    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "tbl_parent")
    public class Parent {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private Long id;

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
        private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_child")
@ToString(exclude = "parent")
public class Child {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "child_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;
}
```

However, I had StackOverFlow for method findAll() for Parent entity as far as infinite loop occurred during serialization.

Then I added property in application.yml:

```
spring:jsp:open-in-view: false
```

And had another problem with serialization. To solve it I added dependency in build.gradle:

```
implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5"
```

And configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule() {
        return new JavaTimeModule();
    }

    @Bean
    public Jdk8Module jdk8TimeModule() {
        return new Jdk8Module();
    }

    @Bean
    public Hibernate5Module hibernate5Module() {
        return new Hibernate5Module();
    }

}
```

Now I have no error but list in parent entity is always null.

What I'm doing wrong? How can I fetch all related children entities without StackOverflow?

Comment: Can you show the data you have in the database? And how are you querying for them

Comment: I'm not sure why data is needed in this case. I created interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long>, just common case

Comment: For now sql statement looks smth like select *  from parent. As I said, it just doesn't fetch related children entities. Just one select from parent table.

Comment: So if you're selecting from parent table, then why do you expect children to appear?

Comment: And you think data is not needed, when you have a problem fetching data?

Comment: In order to isolate the issue to whether it is related to hibernate or it is not related to hibernate but related to recursion of bi-directional during serialisation, the question need more info. If it is the second case, i.e `if rest endpoint is returning `Parent` object as response`, you can try this to troubleshoot. If it is the first issue, it is likely data and question will need more info for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63009621/how-to-deal-with-circular-references-in-jpa-and-hibernate-with-associative-entit/63010032#63010032

Answer (score 0):

@Data annotation from Lombok can cause stackoverflows due to circular dependencies between classes if both classes have @Data and collections/toStrings mentioning each other.

See [Lombok.hashCode issue with "java.lang.StackOverflowError: null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972895/lombok-hashcode-issue-with-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-null)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is quite simple: you cannot hope to serialize both sides of a bidirectional association. If you try to do that, you'll get a JSON representation of `Parent` with a `children` property, and each object in `children` will have a `parent` property, with each `parent` containing a `children` property, and so on, *ad nauseam*.

From what you describe, I'm assuming you want to opt out of serializing the `parent` property, in which case you should put `@JsonIgnore` on `Child.parent`.

Also, since you enabled the `HibernateModule`, which by default ignores lazy properties, you should either disable it, enable its `FORCE_LAZY_LOADING` feature, or configure `Parent.children` to be eagerly fetched. The third option also eliminates the need for `@JsonIgnore`.

(all three options have potentially far-reaching consequences, so you need to decide which one works best for your use case; also note that having to use `open-jpa-in-view` is a code smell, because forcing the lazy load happens outside of any transactional context)